# Swift: Could not cast value of type Swift.Int16 to Swift.AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Getting the error message  'Could not cast value of type Swift.Int16  to Swift.AnyObject' when I run the line of code below. The error occurs on the line:

'newWorkout.setValue(totalTimeConverted as! AnyObject, forKey: "workoutTime")'

Workout is the name of my entity. It has two attributes;

- workoutDate of type NSDate
- workoutTime of type Int16.

  ```
  let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext


  let newWorkout = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Workout", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Workout

  let totalTimeConverted = Int16(totalTime)

  // Add parameters
  newWorkout.setValue(totalTimeConverted as! AnyObject, forKey: "workoutTime")
  newWorkout.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "workoutDate")


  do {
      try context.save()
  } catch {
      print("Error saving data")
  }


  do {
      let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Workout")
      let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
      if results.count > 0 {

      for item in results as! [NSManagedObject]{

          let time = item.valueForKey("workoutTime")
          let workoutDate = item.valueForKey("workoutDate")
          print(time!, workoutDate!)

      }
      }
  } catch{
      print("Error loading data")
  }
  ```

Comment: Why are you casting to `AnyObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cast `Int16` to `AnyObject`. It is value type and not class.

You can use `NSInteger` to do proper typecasting

```
newWorkout.setValue(NSInteger(totalTimeConverted), forKey: "workoutTime")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Can I ask when I execute the code the value for workoutDate is nil. What reason would this be for?

Comment: There are no obvious reasons why it would be nil. You need to do some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `Int16` is a primitive, not object, just is can't be cast to "AnyObject".

As [Dalija Prasnikar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38747513/3141234) points out, you can wrap your number into an NSNumber object.

Comment: Im new to using coredata and got recommended this method. When I change the code to that, i get the error 'Type 'Workout' has no subscript members'

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your reply anyways!